# Program crashes with segmentation fault

Tags: segmentation-fault, fortran

I am using CodeBlocks IDE 20.03 with the GNU Fortran Compiler in order to build a fortran program with many modules. The main program reads in a .inp file, .xml file, and a .dat file and then calls the main module (sweep.f90) which further uses the rest of the modules. The program is compiled successfully and a .exe is produced. I then placed all 3 input files in the same folder as the executable and then executed the .exe file. The .exe crashes with a SIGSEGV Segmentation fault error. I therefore ran the debugger to try to get more details about the error and got the following:

```
#0 ??   __chkstk_ms () (../../../src/gcc-6.3.0/libgcc/config/i386/cygwin.S:172)
#1 0x42d5df profile_driver_input::readallsettings(file=<error reading variable: Cannot access 
   memory at address 0x439b00>, set=..., flag=0, _file=9 
   (D:\...\Fortran\sweep2\source\profile_driver_input.f90:121)
#2 0x431b7f profile_driver_program(D:\...\Fortran\sweep2\source\profile_driver_program.f90:69)
#3 0x432414 main(argc=1, argv=0x1933c98 
   (D:\...\Fortran\sweep2\source\profile_driver_program.f90:45)
#4 0x401288 _Jv_RegisterClasses () (??:??)
#5 0x4012f5 mainCRTStartup () (??:??)
```

where ReadAllSettings is a sub-routine located in a module called profile_driver_input.f90 which is called inside profile_driver_program.f90 as such:

```
Program Profile_Driver_Program
Use Profile_Driver_Input
Implicit None

! PARAMETERS.
Character(LEN=*), Parameter :: setfile = "sweep.inp" ! Settings file 
name.

! VARIABLES.
Type(Settings)    :: sim  ! Simulation settings.
Type(ChemProfile) :: chem ! Chemistry profile.

! Counters and time step variables.
Integer :: err, i, irun, iint
Real :: t, tstop, dt

! EXECUTABLE CODE.

! Load settings file.
Call CommandLine(sim)
Call ReadAllSettings(setfile, sim, err)
If (err /= 0) Then
    Print *, "FAILED to read settings file!  Quitting..."
    Stop
End If
End program
```

and the subroutine in profile_driver_input.f90 looks something like this:

```
Module Profile_Driver_Input
Use LIST_T
!Use Sweep
Implicit None
Public

Integer, Parameter :: UIN = 102
Integer, Parameter :: MAX_POINTS=1000, MAX_VARS=200

Type Settings
    ! Control parameters.
    Logical :: Solve=.True., PostProcess=.True.
    ! Input files.
    Character(LEN=200) :: MechFile=""  ! Particle mechanism file 
    name.
    Character(LEN=200) :: ChemFile=""  ! Chemistry profile file name.
    ! Time stepping variables.
    Type(LIST_DP)  :: Times  ! Times between PSL outputs (first entry 
    is start time).
    Type(LIST_INT) :: Steps  ! Steps between output times.
    Integer        :: Runs=0 ! Number of runs to perform.
End Type

Type ChemProfile
    Integer :: NVARS=0, NPOINTS=0
    Character(LEN=16), Pointer :: Header(:)
    Real, Pointer :: Times(:), Chem(:,:)
    Integer :: iT=0, iP=0, iA=0
End Type

Contains

! -------------------------------------------------------

Subroutine CommandLine(sim)
    ! DESCRIPTION.
    !   Reads program settings from the command line.

    !#ifdef _WIN32
    !Use DFLIB, Only: NARGS, GETARG
    !#endif
    Implicit None

    ! ARGUMENTS.
    Type(Settings), Intent(INOUT) :: sim

    ! VARIABLES.
    Integer(4) :: N, i
    Character(LEN=128) :: arg

    ! EXECUTABLE CODE.
    N = command_argument_count()
    i = 1

    Do While (i <= N)
        Call get_command_argument(i, arg)
        Select Case (arg)
            Case ("-po","/po","\po")
                sim%Solve = .False.
                sim%PostProcess = .True.
        End Select
        i = i + 1
    End Do
End Subroutine
! -------------------------------------------------------

Subroutine ReadAllSettings(file, set, flag)
    ! DESCRIPTION:
    !   Reads a standard settings file and returns
    !   all the program settings for the desired
    !   simulation.

    Use SettingsFileReader
    Implicit None

    ! ARGUMENTS.
    Character(LEN=*), Intent(IN)  :: file ! File to read.
    Type(Settings), Intent(INOUT) :: set  ! Somewhere to put 
    settings.
    Integer, Intent(OUT)          :: flag ! Error flag.

    ! VARIABLES.
    Integer :: i, int, err
    Double Precision :: dp
    Character(LEN=100) :: str
    Type(FileData) :: fdata

    ! EXECUTABLE CODE.
    flag = 0

    ! Load settings file.
    Call LoadSettingsFile(file, UIN, fdata, err)
    If (err /= 0) Return
End Subroutine
End Module
```

I am not really sure what that error means. Could this be a problem of the way I am executing the .exe ? (because I am not sure of that either). Any help would be really appreciated as my knowledge in fortran is limited. Thank you in advance.

In addition to profile_driver_input.f90, two other modules are necessary to compile the program:

List_t.f90

```
Module LIST_DP_T
Implicit None
Public

Type LIST_DP
    Integer :: Count = 0
    Double Precision, Pointer :: Items(:)
End Type

Interface Assignment(=)
    Module Procedure SetP_list_dp
End Interface

Interface Operator(+)
    Module Procedure Add
    Module Procedure AddItem_list_dp
    Module Procedure AddItems
End Interface

Contains

! -------------------------------------------------------

Subroutine Destroy(list)
    ! DESCRIPTION
    !   Clears memory associated with a list type.

    ! ARGUMENTS.
    Type(LIST_DP), Intent(INOUT) :: list

    ! VARIABLES.
    Integer :: err = 0

    ! EXECUTABLE CODE.
    list%Count = 0
    Deallocate(list%Items, STAT=err)
    Nullify(list%Items)
End Subroutine

! -------------------------------------------------------

Subroutine SetP_list_dp(new, old)
    ! DESCRIPTION
    !   Assigns the list of one list type to another
    !   by passing the list pointer.

    ! ARGUMENTS.
    Type(LIST_DP), Intent(INOUT) :: new
    Type(LIST_DP), Intent(IN)    :: old

    ! EXECUTABLE CODE.
    new%Count = old%Count
    new%Items => old%Items
End Subroutine

! -------------------------------------------------------

Subroutine Copy(new, old)
    ! DESCRIPTION
    !   Copies the list of one list type to another.

    ! ARGUMENTS.
    Type(LIST_DP), Intent(INOUT) :: new
    Type(LIST_DP), Intent(IN)    :: old

    ! EXECUTABLE CODE.
    new%Count = old%Count
    new%Items = old%Items
End Subroutine

! -------------------------------------------------------

Function Add(list1, list2) Result (sumlist)
    ! DESCRIPTION
    !   Adds together two list and
    !   returns a new list.

    ! ARGUMENTS.
    Type(LIST_DP), Intent(IN) :: list1
    Type(LIST_DP), Intent(IN) :: list2
    Type(LIST_DP) :: sumlist

    ! VARIABLES.
    Integer :: err = 0
    Double Precision :: items(list1%Count+list2%Count)

    ! EXECUTABLE CODE.

    ! Save current list.
    If (list1%Count > 0) items(1:list1%Count) = list1%Items
    If (list2%Count > 0) items(list1%Count+1:) = list2%Items

    ! Resize list.
    Deallocate(sumlist%Items, STAT=err)
    sumlist%Count = list1%Count + list2%Count
    Allocate(sumlist%Items(sumlist%Count), STAT=err)

    ! Assign back the list.
    sumlist%Items = items
End Function

! -------------------------------------------------------

Function AddItem_list_dp(list, item) Result (newlist)
    ! DESCRIPTION
    !   Adds a number to the end of the list and
    !   returns a new list.

    ! ARGUMENTS.
    Type(LIST_DP), Intent(IN)    :: list
    Double Precision, Intent(IN) :: item
    Type(LIST_DP) :: newlist

    ! VARIABLES.
    Integer :: err = 0
    Double Precision :: items(list%Count+1)

    ! EXECUTABLE CODE.

    ! Save current list.
    If (list%Count > 0) items(1:list%Count) = list%Items
    items(list%Count+1) = item

    ! Resize list.
    Deallocate(newlist%Items, STAT=err)
    newlist%Count = list%Count + 1
    Allocate(newlist%Items(newlist%Count), STAT=err)

    ! Assign back the list.
    newlist%Items = items
End Function

! -------------------------------------------------------

Function AddItems(list, items) Result (newlist)
    ! DESCRIPTION
    !   Adds some numbers to the end of the list and
    !   returns a new list.

    ! ARGUMENTS.
    Type(LIST_DP), Intent(IN)    :: list
    Double Precision, Intent(IN) :: items(:)
    Type(LIST_DP) :: newlist

    ! VARIABLES.
    Integer :: err = 0
    Double Precision :: allitems(list%Count+Size(items))

    ! EXECUTABLE CODE.

    ! Save current list.
    If (list%Count > 0) allitems(1:list%Count) = list%Items
    allitems(list%Count+1:) = items

    ! Resize list.
    Deallocate(newlist%Items, STAT=err)
    newlist%Count = list%Count + Size(items)
    Allocate(newlist%Items(newlist%Count), STAT=err)

    ! Assign back the list.
    newlist%Items = allitems
End Function

! -------------------------------------------------------

Double Precision Function SumList(list)
    ! DESCRIPTION
    !   Returns the sum of the list items.
    Type(LIST_DP), Intent(IN) :: list
    SumList = Sum(list%Items)
End Function

End Module

! =======================================================

Module LIST_INT_T
Implicit None
Public

Type LIST_INT
    Integer :: Count = 0
    Integer, Pointer :: Items(:)
End Type

Interface Assignment(=)
    Module Procedure SetP_list_t
End Interface

Interface Operator(+)
    Module Procedure Add
    Module Procedure AddItem_list_t
    Module Procedure AddItems
End Interface

Contains

! -------------------------------------------------------

Subroutine Destroy(list)
    ! DESCRIPTION
    !   Clears memory associated with a list type.

    ! ARGUMENTS.
    Type(LIST_INT), Intent(INOUT) :: list

    ! VARIABLES.
    Integer :: err = 0

    ! EXECUTABLE CODE.
    list%Count = 0
    Deallocate(list%Items, STAT=err)
    Nullify(list%Items)
End Subroutine

! -------------------------------------------------------

Subroutine SetP_list_t(new, old)
    ! DESCRIPTION
    !   Assigns the list of one list type to another
    !   by passing the list pointer.

    ! ARGUMENTS.
    Type(LIST_INT), Intent(INOUT) :: new
    Type(LIST_INT), Intent(IN)    :: old

    ! EXECUTABLE CODE.
    new%Count = old%Count
    new%Items => old%Items
End Subroutine

! -------------------------------------------------------

Subroutine Copy(new, old)
    ! DESCRIPTION
    !   Copies the list of one list type to another.

    ! ARGUMENTS.
    Type(LIST_INT), Intent(INOUT) :: new
    Type(LIST_INT), Intent(IN)    :: old

    ! EXECUTABLE CODE.
    new%Count = old%Count
    new%Items = old%Items
End Subroutine

! -------------------------------------------------------

Function Add(list1, list2) Result (sumlist)
    ! DESCRIPTION
    !   Adds together two list and
    !   returns a new list.

    ! ARGUMENTS.
    Type(LIST_INT), Intent(IN) :: list1
    Type(LIST_INT), Intent(IN) :: list2
    Type(LIST_INT) :: sumlist

    ! VARIABLES.
    Integer :: err = 0
    Integer :: items(list1%Count+list2%Count)

    ! EXECUTABLE CODE.

    ! Save current list.
    If (list1%Count > 0) items(1:list1%Count) = list1%Items
    If (list2%Count > 0) items(list1%Count+1:) = list2%Items

    ! Resize list.
    Deallocate(sumlist%Items, STAT=err)
    sumlist%Count = list1%Count + list2%Count
    Allocate(sumlist%Items(sumlist%Count), STAT=err)

    ! Assign back the list.
    sumlist%Items = items
End Function

! -------------------------------------------------------

Function AddItem_list_t(list, item) Result (newlist)
    ! DESCRIPTION
    !   Adds a number to the end of the list and
    !   returns a new list.

    ! ARGUMENTS.
    Type(LIST_INT), Intent(IN)    :: list
    Integer, Intent(IN) :: item
    Type(LIST_INT) :: newlist

    ! VARIABLES.
    Integer :: err = 0
    Integer :: items(list%Count+1)

    ! EXECUTABLE CODE.

    ! Save current list.
    If (list%Count > 0) items(1:list%Count) = list%Items
    items(list%Count+1) = item

    ! Resize list.
    Deallocate(newlist%Items, STAT=err)
    newlist%Count = list%Count + 1
    Allocate(newlist%Items(newlist%Count), STAT=err)

    ! Assign back the list.
    newlist%Items = items
End Function

! -------------------------------------------------------

Function AddItems(list, items) Result (newlist)
    ! DESCRIPTION
    !   Adds some numbers to the end of the list and
    !   returns a new list.

    ! ARGUMENTS.
    Type(LIST_INT), Intent(IN)    :: list
    Integer, Intent(IN) :: items(:)
    Type(LIST_INT) :: newlist

    ! VARIABLES.
    Integer :: err = 0
    Integer :: allitems(list%Count+Size(items))

    ! EXECUTABLE CODE.

    ! Save current list.
    If (list%Count > 0) allitems(1:list%Count) = list%Items
    allitems(list%Count+1:) = items

    ! Resize list.
    Deallocate(newlist%Items, STAT=err)
    newlist%Count = list%Count + Size(items)
    Allocate(newlist%Items(newlist%Count), STAT=err)

    ! Assign back the list.
    newlist%Items = allitems
End Function

! -------------------------------------------------------

Integer Function SumList(list)
    ! DESCRIPTION
    !   Returns the sum of the list items.
    Type(LIST_INT), Intent(IN) :: list
    SumList = Sum(list%Items)
End Function

End Module

! =======================================================

Module LIST_T
Use LIST_DP_T
Use LIST_INT_T
Implicit None
Public
End Module
```

and settings_file_reader.f90

```
Module SettingsFileReader
Implicit None
Private
Public :: LoadSettingsFile
! -------------------------------------------------------
! PARAMETERS.
! -------------------------------------------------------

Integer, Private, Parameter :: LKEY = 20  ! Length of a keyword string.
Integer, Private, Parameter :: LSTR = 200 ! Length of a descriptive 
string.
Integer, Private, Parameter :: MAX_NPARAMS = 200 ! Max. number of 
parameters after a keyword.
Integer, Private, Parameter :: MAX_NLINES  = 200 ! Max. number of lines 
in a file.

! -------------------------------------------------------
! DERIVED TYPES.
! -------------------------------------------------------

Type, Private :: LineData
    Character(LEN=LKEY) :: Key=""
    Character(LEN=LSTR) :: Params(MAX_NPARAMS)=""
End Type

Type, Public :: FileData
    Character(LEN=LSTR) :: Name=""           ! File name.
    Integer             :: NLines=0          ! Line count in file.
    Type(LineData)      :: Lines(MAX_NLINES) ! Lines in file.
End Type

Contains

! -------------------------------------------------------

Subroutine LoadSettingsFile(file, unit, fdata, flag)
    ! DESCRIPTION:
    !   Parses a settings file and stores the data
    !   in a FileData type, supplied by the calling code.

    !Use StrConv
    Implicit None

    ! ARGUMENTS.
    Character(LEN=*), Intent(IN) :: file  ! File name to read.
    Integer, Intent(IN)          :: unit  ! Unit number on which to open 
    file.
    Type(FileData), Intent(OUT)  :: fdata ! Settings data from file.
    Integer, Intent(OUT)         :: flag  ! Error flag.

    ! VARIABLES.
    Integer :: i, err
    Character(LEN=5000) :: line
    Character(LEN=LSTR) :: subs(MAX_NPARAMS+1)

    ! EXECUTABLE CODE.
    flag = 0
    i = 0

    ! Open file for reading.
    Open(UNIT=unit, FILE=file, FORM="FORMATTED", &
         STATUS="OLD", ACTION="READ", IOSTAT=err)

    If (err /= 0) Then
        ! Failed to open file.
        flag = -1
        Return
    End If


    Do
        ! Read line from text file.
        line = ""
        Read(UNIT=unit, FMT="(A)", IOSTAT=err) line

        If (err == -2) Then
            ! EOR: not applicable here.
        ElseIf (err == -1) Then
            ! EOF: we have read all the data rows so
            ! exit loop.
            Exit
        ElseIf (err == 0) Then
            ! Normal read, no problems.
        ElseIf (err > 0) Then
            ! Error occured when reading.
            flag = -2
            Exit
        End If


        ! Split the line into substrings.
        !Call SplitString(line, " ", subs, LSTR, MAX_NPARAMS+1, .True.)

        ! Save line in FileData.
        i = i + 1
        fdata%Lines(i)%Key    = subs(1)
        fdata%Lines(i)%Params = subs(2:)
    End Do

    ! Save file name and line count.
    fdata%Name   = file
    fdata%NLines = i

    ! Close input file.
    Close (UNIT=unit, IOSTAT=err)
End Subroutine
```

Here is an example of the input files to the executable:

sweep.inp:

```
CHEMFILE jw1.69.dat
MECHFILE sweep.xml

RUNS 10

STARTT 0.0D0
TIME 1.0D-2 400
TIME 1.42D-3 200

PCOUNT 2048
MAXM0 2.0e11
ACTSURFMODEL profile

OUTPUTFILE jw1.69_out
```

where the chemical and mechanical files are shown here below:

jw1.69.dat

```
172 11                                      
Time    C2H2    H2  H   O2  OH  H2O CO  A4  T   P   Alpha
0   1.38E-08    6.95E-07    3.52E-15    6.62E-06    6.76E-16    6.39E-07     
0   1.19E-17    298 1   0.999990009
0.000259079 1.41E-08    6.90E-07    3.47E-15    6.35E-06    6.71E-16     
6.42E-07    0   1.38E-17    308.9   1   0.999989321
0.000509139 1.43E-08    6.84E-07    2.13E-15    6.10E-06    5.64E-16     
6.46E-07    0   1.60E-17    319.8   1   0.999988585
0.0009838   1.49E-08    6.75E-07    8.31E-16    5.65E-06    3.85E-16     
6.52E-07    0   2.13E-17    341.6   1   0.999986959
0.001428385 1.54E-08    6.67E-07    3.59E-16    5.26E-06    3.33E-16     
6.58E-07    0   2.81E-17    363.4   1   0.9999851
```

and sweep.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<mechanism name="abf soot">
<!-- Choose which models to use -->
<model id="haca"/>
<model id="actsurf" type="abf"/>    
<!-- Define particle types and components. -->
<particle id="[X]"/>

<component id="C">
    <density>1.8</density>
    <molwt>12.011</molwt>
</component>

<!-- Tracker variables -->

<track id="H"/>

<!-- Inceptions -->

<inception name="Pyrene inception">
    <formula>A4 + A4 to [X32]</formula>
    <reactant id="A4" stoich="2" m="3.19e-22" d="0.79e-7"/>
    <particleout id="[X]"/>
    <component id="C" dx="32"/>
    <track id="H" dx="20"/>
</inception>

<!-- Surface reactions (single particle events) -->

<reaction type="surface" name="OH oxidation" defer="true">
    <formula>[X] + OH to [X-1] + CO + H</formula>        
    <reactant id="OH" stoich="1"/>
    <product id="CO" stoich="1"/>
    <product id="H" stoich="1"/>
    <A>2.1693357e26</A>
    <n>0.5</n>
    <E>0.0</E>
    <particleterm id="d" power="2.0"/>
    <component id="C" dx="-1"/>
</reaction>

<reaction type="surface" name="C2H2 addition" defer="true">
    <formula>[X] + C2H2 to [X+2] + H</formula>
    <reactant id="C2H2" stoich="1"/>
    <product id="H" stoich="1"/>
    <particlein id="[X]"/>
    <particleout id="[X]"/>
    <A>8.0E7</A>
    <n>1.56</n>
    <E units="cal">3.8E0</E>
    <particleterm id="as" power="1.0"/>
    <component id="C" dx="2"/>
    <track id="H" dx="+1"/>
</reaction>

<reaction type="surface" name="O2 oxidation" defer="true">
    <formula>[X] + O2 to [X-2] + 2CO</formula>
    <reactant id="O2" stoich="1"/>
    <product id="CO" stoich="2"/>
    <A>2.2e12</A>
    <n>0.0</n>
    <E units="cal">7.5</E>
    <particleterm id="as" power="1.0"/>
    <component id="C" dx="-2"/>
</reaction>

<!-- Condensation reactions (single particle events) -->

<reaction type="condensation" name="A4 condensation" defer="true">
    <formula>[X] + A4 to [X+16]</formula>        
    <reactant id="A4" stoich="1" m="3.19e-22" d="0.79e-7"/>
    <component id="C" dx="+16"/>
    <track id="H" dx="+10"/>
</reaction>

</mechanism>
```

Most of the program functionality have been eliminated and so the input files might have extra information.

Comment: Segmentation fault can be almost anything. Array out of bounds, interface mismatch, stack corruption, heap corruption... A real [mcve] will likely be necessary. What is line 121?

Comment: Hi @VladimirF. Line 121 is the first line shown in the code profile_driver_input.f90 above. Regarding a minimal reproducible example, I have simplified the program as much as possible, eliminating all the functionality of the code and focusing on reading the input files in order to reproduce the error. How would you like me to share the files?

Comment: Code should be pasted inside the question itself.